# Laravel 8 not validating pdf file

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel version 8 and I wanted to validate the uploaded file should be a pdf file, I am using the below code

```php
$request->validate([
      'cv'=> 'required|mimes:pdf|max:2048'
]);
```

but the problem is that I still get the error of "The cv must be a file of type:  pdf" even though I am uploading a pdf file.

solved by adding enctype="multipart/form-data" atrribute in form tag

Answer (score 0):

you can use [mimetypes](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/validation#rule-mimetypes) validation:

```
$request->validate([
      'cv'=> 'required|mimetypes:application/pdf|max:10000'
]);
```

Comment: i still get this "The cv must be a file of type: application/pdf."

Comment: are you sure that file has the extension .pdf?

Comment: yeah even I tried to add other extensions like jpeg  just to test even those extensions are not being validated

Comment: solved by adding enctype="multipart/form-data" atrribute in form tag

Answer (score 0):

Before 5.2

```
$rules  = [
    "file" => "required|mimes:pdf|max:10000"
]
```

From laravel Docs:

Even though you only need to specify the extensions, this rule actually validates against the MIME type of the file by reading the file's contents and guessing its MIME type.

After 5.2 Update:

Starting from Laravel 5.2, you could validate file upload against full MIME type, new validation rule called: mimetypes.

```
$rules  = [
    "file" => "required|mimetypes:application/pdf|max:10000"
]
```

Comment: this comes now "The cv must be a file of type: application/pdf."

Comment: solved by adding enctype="multipart/form-data" atrribute in form tag